# Integration of partial derivative $ f_{k}(x+t e_{j})-f_{k}(x)=\int_{0}^{t} \partial_{j} f_{k}(x+s e_{j}) d s$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In this post [Schwartz space is Frechet space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375020/schwarz-space-is-frechet-space) they have

> Denoting by $e_{j}$ the vector $(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ with the 1
> in the $j$ th position, we have $$ f_{k}\left(x+t
>  e_{j}\right)-f_{k}(x)=\int_{0}^{t} \partial_{j} f_{k}\left(x+s
>  e_{j}\right) d s . $$

why this integral is true?

Comment: Yes, the directional derivative along $e_j$ and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Let $j,k$ and $x$ be fixed, and then apply standard 1D FTC to the function $F(t):= f_k(x+te_j)$